# .net Framework composite API post parameter

Tags: c#, .net, api

How would one go about combining 2 classes for a parameter on a post api endpoint?

We have a User class with email and password, and then a FarmUser that contains UserID from the User class as well as name, surname, address , cell no etc.

When you register on the system it needs to take all of those combined and split them to be saved to the respectable tables. But I have no idea how to go about this.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Create a composite class with the class you have for example user and FarmUser.

Comment: It depends of your ORM. (can you tell me witch one you are using ?) You can make inheritance for your entities and map them to make the database structure you described. (We can do it with NHibernate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BASE MODEL

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

INHERITED MODEL

```
public class FarmUser : User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string CellNo { get; set; }
}
```

API Controller

```
public void Post([FromBody] FarmUser data)
{
     // Some code here
}
```

Sample JSON data to POST on the API

> As long as the property name in your class is also the same as the json data you pass in the api controller (for a basic demo).

```
{
"firstName": "Tonton",
"lastName": "Sevilla",
"address": "Manila, Philippines",
"cellNo": "+639191234567",
"id": 1,
"email": "tonton@example.com",
"password": "Password1234"
```

}

OUTPUT:
[image]